# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files\Apache on launching ActiveMQ

Tags: java, apache, exception, jms, activemq-classic

I've downloaded Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 and I'm trying to launch it. Following, the command I've typed and the output:

```
c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-activemq-5.9.0>bin\activemq
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files\Apache
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Apache
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Files\Apache.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

I'm following the official guide on [Running an ActiveMQ Broker](http://activemq.apache.org/run-broker.html) and I'm working under Windows 7.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. The issue is related to the white spaces in the path; indeed, `Files\Apache` in the exception message refers to a part of the path `c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-activemq-5.9.0>bin\activemq`. I've quickly solved it moving the ActiveMQ folder to a "whitespace-free" path and now it works.